# Spanish Football Calendar

Tags: football, schedule, la-liga

I've booked tickets to watch FC Barcelona play Athletic Club Bilbao, currently scheduled for Sunday 18th March, 2018. Since the date and time won't generally be confirmed until about 2 weeks prior to this date, I'm wondering whether there is any chance this game would be rearranged for a different weekend?

Would it be moved to a different weekend to cater to cup matches, for example? Or if I booked to stay in Barcelona (Flying from the UK) from Friday 16th until Tuesday 20th, would the match definitely be within this period and make it safe to book now whilst prices are low?

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from [La Liga website](http://www.laliga.es/en/other-competitions/copa-del-rey/semifinals), there are no cup matches in March. And generally, cup matches never clash with La Liga matches, and the only instance when La Liga games are rescheduled due to clashes with other tournaments is in December if a La Liga team plays in Club World Cup, in which neither Barcelona nor Athletic Club participate this season.

The dates you booked your stay are completely safe, cause even if the match will be rescheduled it may only be played on Saturday instead of Sunday, as Barcelona and Real Madrid play their matches only during weekends due to TV rights agreement.